# simple-xml NodeBuilder No Class Def Found Error on Raspberry Pi running Kura

Tags: java, osgi, raspberry-pi, simple-framework

I have an OSGi bundle that uses SimpleXML as an imported jar (The SimpleXML jar is well defined on the bundle class path and is included in the exported bundle), the bundle works fine in the Kura emulator inside Eclipse, But when the bundle is deployed to Raspberry Pi, starting the bundle will throw an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeBuilder
```

Anyone has encountered this problem?

-- UPDATE: I got it to work by exporting and importing SimpleXML from my Bundle and having a simpleXML Bundle active as well on the device. (Which I don't think is the solution, but is working for now). Ideally the SimpleXML jar should work without being exposed outside my bundle.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.kura.test.implementation
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Export-Package: org.eclipse.kura.test.implementation,
 org.simpleframework.xml,
 org.simpleframework.xml.convert,
 org.simpleframework.xml.core,
 org.simpleframework.xml.filter,
 org.simpleframework.xml.strategy,
 org.simpleframework.xml.stream,
 org.simpleframework.xml.transform,
 org.simpleframework.xml.util
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 jar/org.simpleframework.simple-xml.2.3.jar
Import-Package: org.eclipse.kura.test.api,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.7.0",
 org.osgi.service.component;version="1.2.0",
 org.simpleframework.xml,
 org.simpleframework.xml.convert,
 org.simpleframework.xml.core,
 org.simpleframework.xml.filter,
 org.simpleframework.xml.strategy,
 org.simpleframework.xml.stream,
 org.simpleframework.xml.transform,
 org.simpleframework.xml.util
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/component.xml
Require-Bundle: slf4j.api
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Comment: It would help to see your Manifest

Comment: It would be useful to see the full stacktrace as in that case the code of SimpleXML could be analyzed (how it tries to load the class).